# Push notification on Android Jelly Bean OS

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-4.2-jelly-bean

We noticed that the Jelly Bean OS has a "Show notifications" setting under the "App Info" section.

We have been implementing push notifications for our app, where we ask the user if they allow push notifications when they first launch the app.
Since there was no global notification setting available in pre Jelly Bean (JB) versions, we had the notifications ON/OFF toggle inside our app in the settings menu.
However, since JB devices have a notification setting outside of the app that the user could toggle, now we would need to keep track of 2 toggles (one outside the app and one inside the app).

What is the recommended best practice for notifications on JB devices?  Is there an API that we can use such that we know whether the user has "Notifications" enabled or not outside of our app?

Thank you.

Comment: do you have a way to programmatically read the "App Info" setting?  Of course you cannot set it programmatically, although that ability is sought in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611635/how-to-turn-on-the-application-setting-show-notifications-in-4-1-jelly-bean-fo

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure but I do not think you will have to keep track of both toggles.  I would assume the one on the System -> Apps area will override whatever you do.  So:

Your App On,
System App On
- Notification On!

Your App On,
System App Off
- Notification Off!

Your App Off,
System App On
- Notification Off!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing a simple test case to verify it. Create an app that tries to launch a notification, run it, verify you get the notification. Dismiss the notification, uncheck "Show Notifications" for your test app, and run it again. I'm inclined to believe that the NotificationManager just ignores your request to show a notification if the user has turned notifications off for your app. You *likely* don't have to do anything in your app to support the new os feature.