# How to turn on the Application setting 'Show Notifications' in 4.1 Jelly Bean for Toast Messages

Tags: android, notifications, toast, android-4.2-jelly-bean

My application uses Toast and it no longer works under Android 4.1 (Jelly Bean) unless the Application setting "Show notifications" is checked. Is there a way to programatically set this on? I have looked through the permissions list but have not found anything. Searching discovers an outstanding issue no. 35013 with Google.

Comment: Allowing an app to change this setting would defeat the entire purpose of the setting.

Comment: not possible as of now unfortunately. Standard is that it is switched on though during the first install. So you shouldnt have any problem in the first place until the user decides that your notifications are disturbing and switches it off.

Comment: That issue is at http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list?can=2&q=show+notifications&colspec=ID+Type+Status+Owner+Summary+Stars&cells=tiles

Comment: What are you doing with Toast? Is it something the user needs to see? Perhaps there's another way you could notify them other than via Toast.